# Expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token while building a MEX-file

Tags: c, linux, matlab, mex, lib

I'm hoping for help installing Andreas Mueller's [MATLAB bindings for Global Probability of Boundary](https://github.com/amueller/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings).

I hope that my issue is not deeply ingrained in my installation, so I'll describe the immediate problem first, with the following paragraph noting some attempts at implementation.

According to Mueller's instructions in the readme, I did my best to install CUDA, ACML, and GCC (currently working on RHEL 7). After a successful build/install of the library `libdamascene.so`, I included a txt file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` which includes the path of `libdamascene.so`. It shows up when I use `ldconfig -p | grep libdamascene.so`.

When I open up MATLAB and try to build the MEX-file (using GCC 6.3) I get

```
Error using mex:
In file included from ../damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/bindings/gpb_mex.c: 3: 0:
../damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/bindings/gpb.h: 10: 143: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token
void gpb(const unsigned int* in)image, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, float* border, int*textons, float* orientations, int device_num=0);
```

And a couple of subsequent errors that I gather are from the fact that the compiler wasn't able to properly read the header.

One thing I tried to do was to simply remove the declaration of `device_num = 0` and place explicitly initialize it in the `gpb_mex.c` function call. This result is more nebulous.

```
Error using mex
/tmp/mex_1295917814264136_135235/gpb_mex.o: In function 'mexFunction':
gpb_mex.c: (.text+0x161): undefined reference to gpb
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

This error makes me thing that theres a problem with my library, which is a little more challenging to debug. I won't put all the things I tried (available on demand) to get a successful build of the library but let me summarize:

- I'm running CUDA 9.0, not CUDA 8.0.
- I'm running the `gpuacml` from the AMD Open64 SDK (only one I could find).
- I had to change the `gpu_architecture` in the `CMakelists.txt` master file from `sm_20` to `sm_70`.
- I have a separate installation of GCC 6.3.0 (and GCC 5.3.0) so I can build the library.

My biggest question is: do you think this indeed a matter of an incorrectly built library or is there something else missing. Is there any way I can check if the library `libdamascene.so` is working correctly?
Please let me know how I can clarify my situation. Thank you so much!

Edit: I am including additional data.

Here's MATLAB output when I try to compile the MEX-file.

```
mex -v GCC='/usr/bin/gcc63' G++='/usr/bin/g++63' gpb_mex.c
Verbose mode is on.
... Looking for compiler 'gcc' ...
... Executing command 'which gcc' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gcc').
... Executing command 'gcc -print-file-name=libstdc++.so' ...Yes ('/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libstdc++.so').
Found installed compiler 'gcc'.
Options file details
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Compiler location: /usr/bin/gcc63
    Options file: /home/clusterbomb/.matlab/R2018b/mex_C_glnxa64.xml
    CMDLINE2 : /usr/bin/gcc63 -pthread -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64 -shared  -O -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map" /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/gpb_mex.o /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/c_mexapi_version.o   -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++ -o gpb_mex.mexa64
    CC : /usr/bin/gcc63
    DEFINES : -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
    MATLABMEX : -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
    CFLAGS : -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
    INCLUDE : -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/simulink/include"
    COPTIMFLAGS : -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG
    CDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    LD : /usr/bin/gcc63
    LDFLAGS : -pthread -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64
    LDTYPE : -shared 
    FUNCTIONMAP : "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map"
    VERSIONMAP : "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"
    LINKEXPORT : -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map"
    LINKEXPORTVER : -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"
    LINKLIBS : -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++
    LDOPTIMFLAGS : -O
    LDDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    MWCPPLIB : "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6"
    OBJEXT : .o
    LDEXT : .mexa64
    SETENV : CC="/usr/bin/gcc63"
                CXX="g++"
                CFLAGS="-fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE "
                CXXFLAGS="-fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -std=c++11 -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE "
                COPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG"
                CXXOPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG"
                CDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
                CXXDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
                LD="/usr/bin/gcc63"
                LDXX="g++"
                LDFLAGS="-pthread -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64 -shared  -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++ -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map""
                LDDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
    GCC : /usr/bin/gcc63
    CPPLIBS : /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libstdc++.so
    MATLABROOT : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b
    ARCH : glnxa64
    SRC : "/home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/bindings/gpb_mex.c";"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c"
    OBJ : /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/gpb_mex.o;/tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/c_mexapi_version.o
    OBJS : /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/gpb_mex.o /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/c_mexapi_version.o 
    SRCROOT : /home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/bindings/gpb_mex
    DEF : /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/gpb_mex.def
    EXP : "gpb_mex.exp"
    LIB : "gpb_mex.lib"
    EXE : gpb_mex.mexa64
    ILK : "gpb_mex.ilk"
    MANIFEST : "gpb_mex.mexa64.manifest"
    TEMPNAME : gpb_mex
    EXEDIR : 
    EXENAME : gpb_mex
    G++ : /usr/bin/g++63
    OPTIM : -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG
    LINKOPTIM : -O
    CMDLINE1_0 : /usr/bin/gcc63 -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "/home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/bindings/gpb_mex.c" -o /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/gpb_mex.o
    CMDLINE1_1 : /usr/bin/gcc63 -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c" -o /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/c_mexapi_version.o
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Building with 'gcc'.
/usr/bin/gcc63 -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "/home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/bindings/gpb_mex.c" -o /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/gpb_mex.o
/usr/bin/gcc63 -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c" -o /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/c_mexapi_version.o
/usr/bin/gcc63 -pthread -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64 -shared  -O -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map" /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/gpb_mex.o /tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/c_mexapi_version.o   -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++ -o gpb_mex.mexa64
Error using mex
/tmp/mex_1326595352957888_135235/gpb_mex.o: In function `mexFunction':
gpb_mex.c:(.text+0x161): undefined reference to `gpb'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's the header file `gpb.h` (with edit of removing `device_num=0`):

```
void gpb(const unsigned int* in_image,unsigned int width,unsigned int height, float* border, int* textons, float* orientations, int device_num);
```

Here's the `gpb_mex.c` file with the alteration of addition the declared `device_num` in the final line:

```
#include <mex.h>
#include "gpb.h"

void mexFunction(int nOut, mxArray *pOut[],
         int nIn, const mxArray *pIn[])
{
  mwSize width, height;
  float* borders;
  float* orientations;
  int* textons;
  unsigned int *in_image;
  mwSize dims[3];
  mwSize orientation_dims[3];

  if((nIn != 1) || (nOut != 3))
    mexErrMsgTxt("Usage: border,textons,orientations = gpb(image)");
  if (!mxIsClass(pIn[0],"uint8") || mxGetNumberOfDimensions(pIn[0]) != 3) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Usage: th argument must be a unsigned int matrix");
    }
  const mwSize *indims= mxGetDimensions(pIn[0]);
  if (indims[0]!=4)
      mexErrMsgTxt("Image needs to be of shape 4 x widht x height");
  width = indims[2];
  height = indims[1];
  mexPrintf("width %d, height %d\n",width,height);
  mexPrintf("Element-size: %d, sizeof(int): %d, sizeof(char) %d\n",mxGetElementSize(pIn[0]),sizeof(int),sizeof(unsigned char));
  dims[0]=width; dims[1]=height; //for rgb0
  mexPrintf("width: %d height: %d\n",width, height);
  pOut[0]=mxCreateNumericMatrix(height,width,mxSINGLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
  pOut[1]=mxCreateNumericMatrix(height,width,mxINT32_CLASS,mxREAL);
  orientation_dims[0]=width; orientation_dims[1]=height; orientation_dims[2]=8;
  pOut[2]=mxCreateNumericArray(3,orientation_dims,mxSINGLE_CLASS,mxREAL);

  borders=(float*) mxGetPr(pOut[0]);
  textons=(int*) mxGetPr(pOut[1]);
  orientations=(float*) mxGetPr(pOut[2]);

  in_image = (unsigned int*) mxGetData(pIn[0]);
  gpb(in_image,height,width,borders,textons,orientations, 0); 
}
```

Happy to provide any more source code as need, but the rest would be ripped straight from amueller's repository (link above).

Edit 2:

using -L resulted in a permission error, which I resolved by `sudo chmod 755 libdamascene.so` in linux terminal.

So the good news is that matlab was able to find libdamascene, evidenced by it moving forward after permission denied. Unfortunately, the compiler is still struggling.

```
mex -v GCC='/usr/bin/gcc63' gpb_mex.c -L</home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/build/libdamascene.so>
Verbose mode is on.
... Looking for compiler 'gcc' ...
... Executing command 'which gcc' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gcc').
... Executing command 'gcc -print-file-name=libstdc++.so' ...Yes ('/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libstdc++.so').
Found installed compiler 'gcc'.
Options file details
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Compiler location: /usr/bin/gcc63
    Options file: /home/clusterbomb/.matlab/R2018b/mex_C_glnxa64.xml
    CMDLINE2 : /usr/bin/gcc63 -pthread -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64 -shared  -O -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map" /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/gpb_mex.o /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/c_mexapi_version.o   -L</home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/build/libdamascene.so>   -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++ -o gpb_mex.mexa64
    CC : /usr/bin/gcc63
    DEFINES : -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
    MATLABMEX : -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
    CFLAGS : -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
    INCLUDE : -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/simulink/include"
    COPTIMFLAGS : -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG
    CDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    LD : /usr/bin/gcc63
    LDFLAGS : -pthread -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64
    LDTYPE : -shared 
    FUNCTIONMAP : "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map"
    VERSIONMAP : "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"
    LINKEXPORT : -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map"
    LINKEXPORTVER : -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"
    LINKLIBS : -L</home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/build/libdamascene.so>   -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++
    LDOPTIMFLAGS : -O
    LDDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    MWCPPLIB : "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6"
    OBJEXT : .o
    LDEXT : .mexa64
    SETENV : CC="/usr/bin/gcc63"
                CXX="g++"
                CFLAGS="-fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE "
                CXXFLAGS="-fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -std=c++11 -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE "
                COPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG"
                CXXOPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG"
                CDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
                CXXDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
                LD="/usr/bin/gcc63"
                LDXX="g++"
                LDFLAGS="-pthread -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64 -shared  -L</home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/build/libdamascene.so>   -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++ -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map""
                LDDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
    GCC : /usr/bin/gcc63
    CPPLIBS : /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libstdc++.so
    MATLABROOT : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b
    ARCH : glnxa64
    SRC : "/home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/bindings/gpb_mex.c";"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c"
    OBJ : /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/gpb_mex.o;/tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/c_mexapi_version.o
    OBJS : /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/gpb_mex.o /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/c_mexapi_version.o 
    SRCROOT : /home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/bindings/gpb_mex
    DEF : /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/gpb_mex.def
    EXP : "gpb_mex.exp"
    LIB : "gpb_mex.lib"
    EXE : gpb_mex.mexa64
    ILK : "gpb_mex.ilk"
    MANIFEST : "gpb_mex.mexa64.manifest"
    TEMPNAME : gpb_mex
    EXEDIR : 
    EXENAME : gpb_mex
    OPTIM : -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG
    LINKOPTIM : -O
    CMDLINE1_0 : /usr/bin/gcc63 -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "/home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/bindings/gpb_mex.c" -o /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/gpb_mex.o
    CMDLINE1_1 : /usr/bin/gcc63 -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c" -o /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/c_mexapi_version.o
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Building with 'gcc'.
/usr/bin/gcc63 -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "/home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/bindings/gpb_mex.c" -o /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/gpb_mex.o
/usr/bin/gcc63 -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c" -o /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/c_mexapi_version.o
/usr/bin/gcc63 -pthread -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64 -shared  -O -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/extern/lib/glnxa64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map" /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/gpb_mex.o /tmp/mex_1363958469865432_171081/c_mexapi_version.o   -L</home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/build/libdamascene.so>   -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++ -o gpb_mex.mexa64
/tmp/mex_1363958922594243_171081: line 2: -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64: No such file or directory
Error using mex
The command '/usr/bin/gcc63' exited with a return value '1'
```

I have double and triple checked that the directory /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64 exists (it does). I have also tried `restoredefaultpath` and `rehash toolboxcache` to no avail. No change when I utilize gcc 5.3.0 or the native RHEL 7 gcc. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: These are both compiler errors, they are totally unrelated to the library. It is problems with the source code. Likely you are compiling C++ code with a C compiler, or C++11 code with an older C++ compiler. Hard to tell which without seeing the source code and your compile command.

Comment: You bring hope! I have edited the question to include more information. If you have time, please take another look! Let me know if I can provide more.

Comment: You should use the provided makefile to compile mex.

Comment: @rahnema1 is right, that Makefile adds a bunch of object files that I presume are the CUDA code, which is not included in OP’s attempt at compiling. But it also sets the target architecture to 32 bits, whereas no recent versions of MATLAB are 32-bit. And it misses some compiler flags and declarations that are required for MEX-files to work with the newer versions of MATLAB.  This might not be as easy to fix as I first thought...

Answer (score 2):

In the file `damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings/bindings/gpb.h`, the following line causes the error:

```
void gpb(const unsigned int* in_image,unsigned int width,unsigned int height, float* border, int* textons, float* orientations, int device_num=0);
```

The last argument has a default parameter, which is a C++ feature, an not valid C syntax. Remove the `=0` so it becomes:

```
void gpb(const unsigned int* in_image,unsigned int width,unsigned int height, float* border, int* textons, float* orientations, int device_num);
```

Next, when you call `gpb`, you cannot rely on the default value for `device_num`, so you need to pass this explicitly. In `damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings/bindings/gpb_mex.c`, the line:

```
gpb(in_image,height,width,borders,textons,orientations);
```

needs an additional argument `0`:

```
gpb(in_image,height,width,borders,textons,orientations,0);
```

With these changes, I hope, the code should compile normally with a C compiler.

(I realize that you already did these things...)

Finally, the linker needs to find the `gpb` function. I presume this one is in the `libdamascene.so` library that you built. You need to tell the `mex` command to link in this library:

```
mex -v GCC='/usr/bin/gcc63' gpb_mex.c -ldamascene
```

(the argument to `-l` gets `lib` prepended and `.a` or `.so` appended, to form the name of the library file. Depending on where this library file resides, you might need to also add a `-L<path>` argument to the `mex` call, with `<path>` the directory that contains the library file:

```
mex -v GCC='/usr/bin/gcc63' gpb_mex.c -L/home/clusterbomb/Downloads/GPUGPB/damascene-python-and-matlab-bindings-master/build/libdamascene.so
```

Comment: Thank you, this certainly moved things forward! I really appreciate it. It appears the mex compiler gets itself hung up on the file directory glnxa64, I have appended the question with a second edit. Thank you very much all your help so far. I can open up a new question if you think it is outside this question's perview.

Comment: @DavidKunsberg: I meant replace all of `<path>`... the `<` and `>` symbols have special meaning in the shell, I didn’t mean for those to remain. Sorry for being unclear. :) I’ve edited the answer to be me specific.